# JavaFX client server socket

Tags: java, javafx

I'm setting a mail local service and I've built the server interface with JavaFX.

The problem is that when I run the server, it shows the interface but it's blocked and it doesn't work in any way.

It seems like only the graphics doesn't appear, the backend is working. Indeed if I connect the client and do a request, it all works.
Is it maybe a problem of thread?

This is the main:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainView.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();

stage.setTitle("Server Log");
stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 490, 309));
stage.centerOnScreen();
stage.show();


ServerModel m = new ServerModel(); //create Model
ServerController c = loader.getController(); //get controller
c.setModel(m);
m.start(); //the problem is here, if I comment this line It shows the server interface but obviously the backend doesn't work.
```

The constructor of ServerModel is this:

```
public ServerModel() {
    try {
        serversocket = new ServerSocket(5888); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServerModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
}
```

and this is the start method of the model that attends the client request for socket:

```
public void start(){
    Socket socket = null;
    while (!closed){ //server main loop
        try{
            socket = serversocket.accept();
            //... (here there would be threads that communicate with client and set closed to true)
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're running the server code on the _JavaFX Application Thread_. This will block the thread from doing any GUI related stuff; hence why you must _never_ block, nor do long-running tasks on, the FX thread. You should run the server code on a background thread.

Comment: @Slaw Ok I got it but I don't know how to do it. Can you show me in this example how to do it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: These may help: [Lesson: Concurrency (Java Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), the [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package, [Concurrency in JavaFX (JavaFX Tutorials)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm), and the [`javafx.concurrent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html) package.